# implement 'math' array as web-ready image (e.g. SVG)

Tags: html, svg, mathml

I have the following array (LaTeX code given) that I'd like to make HTML5-friendly via SVG, or MathML, or (more likely) some combination:

```
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
0 &&&& \\ \rule[.6cm]{0pt}{0pt}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & \cdots \\ \rule[.75cm]{0pt}{0pt}
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 & \cdots \\ \rule[.75cm]{0pt}{0pt}
\end{array}
```

I can do this (almost) with MathML, but the next desire becomes problematic: overlaying the array with a (static) snaking arrow that shows the reader how to enumerate the infinite array to show that it is countable.

If I could embed MathML in SVG, I could make this diagram.  But it appears that's not possible.  (HTML tags in an SVG object fail.)  Could a MathML in a canvas element work?  Any pointers would be appreciated.

My ultimate goal is to create mathematics texts in ePUB format.  These are the kinds of problems that are my biggest sticking point, right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using HTML as the container, with MathML and SVG inline in the document. That way it's easy to reposition and stack graphics/equations/text the way you want with CSS.

The other option I can think of is the foreignObject element in svg, which can contain e.g HTML or MathML.

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible to mix MathML and SVG.  The key is to put your MathML inside the foreignObject element.

I don't read Latex, so I don't know what your snaking arrow is supposed to look like, so I settled for putting a box around an equation.  Hopefully that will be enough to demonstrate that it's possible.  Do note that only Firefox 5 seems to display MathML well at this time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <svg id="svg1" width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <rect x="40" y="40" height="100" width="100" style="stroke:black; fill:lightblue"/>
            <foreignObject x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100">
                <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                    <mrow>
                        <mi>A</mi>
                        <mo>=</mo>
                        <mfenced open="[" close="]">
                            <mtable>
                                <mtr>
                                    <mtd><mi>x</mi></mtd>
                                    <mtd><mi>y</mi></mtd>
                                </mtr>
                                <mtr>
                                    <mtd><mi>z</mi></mtd>
                                    <mtd><mi>w</mi></mtd>
                                </mtr>
                            </mtable>
                        </mfenced>
                    </mrow>
                </math>
            </foreignObject>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```